# SMTPTransport and emails with special characters

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

I'm using Spring and JavaMailSenderImpl to send emails. But when I try to send an email to an email address with special characters (conceição-fake@gmail.com) I get the following error:

```
nested exception is:
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 554 5.1.1 concei  o-fake@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table
 org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
nested exception is: 
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 554 5.1.1 concei  o-fake@gmail.com>: 
 Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table
; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 554 5.1.1 concei  o-fake@gmail.com>: 
Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1294)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:635)
```

My JavaMailSenderImpl configuration is:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="host">
        <value>${application.mail.host}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="port">
        <value>${application.mail.port}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${application.mail.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${application.mail.password}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.mime.charset">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And I am using MimeMessage.

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

I think the problem is in:

```
protected void sendCommand(String cmd) throws MessagingException {
    sendCommand(ASCIIUtility.getBytes(cmd));
}
```

The code sends the addresses to the mail server but when it converts to bytes dont have in consideration the non-ASCII characters.

So it is not possible to use the Spring Framework to send emails to addresses with special characters?

Comment: The mail address is not a valid address as defined by RFC5322. Probably your mail server is not RFC6530 compliant? See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Internationalization

Comment: I don't think the problem is my mail server because when I send emails via my email account they are received on that address. But I gone check.

Answer (score 0):

My mail server is not RFC6530 compliant.